# Avoiding Dummy variable trap and neural network

Tags: neural-network, regression, one-hot-encoding

I know that categorical data should be one-hot encoded before training the machine learning algorithm. I also need that for multivariate linear regression I need to exclude one of the encoded variable to avoid so called dummy variable trap.

Ex: If I have categorical feature "size": "small", "medium", "large", then in one hot encoded I would have something like:

```
small  medium  large other-feature
  0      1       0      2999
```

So to avoid dummy variable trap I need to remove any of the 3 columns, for example, column "small".

Should I do the same for training a Neural Network? Or this is purely for multivariate regression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[As stated here](http://www.bzst.com/2014/03/the-use-of-dummy-variables-in.html), dummy variable trap needs to be avoided (one category of each categorical feature removed after encoding but before training) on input of algorithms that consider all the predictors together, as a linear combination. Such algorithms are:

- Linear/multilinear regression
- Logistic regression
- Discriminant analysis
- Neural networks that don't employ weight decay

If you remove a category from input of a neural network that employs weight decay, it will get biased in favor of the omitted category instead.

Even though no information is lost when omitting one category after encoding a feature, other algorithms will have to infer the correlation of the omitted category indirectly through combination of all the other categories, making them do more computation for the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: In the case of neural networks *without* weight decay, wouldn't non-linear activation functions (relu, tanh, sigmoid...) fix the issue of dummy variable trap?